# Removing unnecessary function from Rust echo server

Tags: rust

This code:

```
use std::io::{TcpListener, TcpStream};
use std::io::{Acceptor, Listener};

fn main() {
    let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1", 5555);

    // bind the listener to the specified address
    let mut acceptor = listener.listen();

    // accept connections and process them, spawning a new tasks for each one
    for stream in acceptor.incoming() {
        match stream {
            Err(e) => { /* connection failed */ }
            Ok(stream) => {
                // connection succeeded
                spawn(proc() {
                    let mut buf: [u8, ..1024] = [0, ..1024];
                    loop {
                        let len = stream.read(buf);
                        let _ = stream.write(buf.slice(0, len.unwrap()));
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

fails with:

```
    Compiling chat v0.1.0 (file:///home/chris/rust/chat)
src/chat.rs:19:35: 19:41 error: cannot borrow immutable captured outer variable in a proc `stream` as mutable
src/chat.rs:19                         let len = stream.read(buf);
                                                 ^~~~~~
src/chat.rs:20:25: 20:31 error: cannot borrow immutable captured outer variable in a proc `stream` as mutable
src/chat.rs:20                         stream.write(buf.slice(0, len.unwrap()));
                                       ^~~~~~
error: aborting due to 2 previous errors
Could not compile `chat`.
```

But if I change the code to:

```
                spawn(proc() {
                    fn handle(mut stream: TcpStream) {
                        let mut buf: [u8, ..1024] = [0, ..1024];
                        loop {
                            let len = stream.read(buf);
                            let _ = stream.write(buf.slice(0, len.unwrap()));
                        }
                    }
                    handle(stream);
                })
```

It works.

Is there a way to remove this `handle` function?

Comment: Change `Ok(stream)` to `Ok(mut stream)`.

Comment: Thanks @Levans - make this an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tricky point in your code is in your pattern. When you write something like:

```
match foo.bar() {
    Some(value) => { ... },
    _ => {}
}
```

You are declaring a new variable (`value` in my example) and move the content of the option into it. It's practically equivalent to :

```
let value = foo.bar().unwrap();
```

So in this situation, nothing forbids to declare it mutable with

```
match foo.bar() {
    Some(mut value) => { ... },
    _ => {}
}
```